# Multiple instances of LightVC on a single server

Tags: php, frameworks

Has anyone been able to configure multiple instances of LightVC on a single server? The goal would be to have any sub folders from the root use the framework.

For instance:

```
domain.com/applicationA/
domain.com/applicationB/
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I split up the files like so:

```
/root/lightvc-2.0.1/classes
/root/lightvc-2.0.1/modules

/root/myvcapp/config
/root/myvcapp/controller
/root/myvcapp/views
```

In /root/myvcapp/config/

@ line 6, I added this:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
```

@ line 10, I added this:

```
define('LIGHTVC_PATH', realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/lightvc-2.0.1") . '/');
```

I changed this block:

```
include(APP_PATH . 'classes/AppController.class.php');
include(APP_PATH . 'classes/AppView.class.php');
```

to this:

```
include(LIGHTVC_PATH .  'classes/AppController.class.php');
include(LIGHTVC_PATH .  'classes/AppView.class.php');
```

There is still a need to block access to */myvcapp/config*, */myvcapp/controller* and */myvcapp/views*. I plan to do this using httpd.conf.